# Regarding simple pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

When I was going through the wikipedia article I have read
clock pendulums are usually made of a weight or bob attached to the bottom end of a rod, with the top attached to a pivot so it can swing. The advantage of this construction is that it positions the centre of mass close to the physical end of the pendulum, farthest from the pivot. This maximizes the moment of inertia, and minimises the length of pendulum required for a given period

Now I don't understand how does moment of Inertia affect the time period

May I please know how will inertia affect the time period of the
simple pendulum

Comment: the question from thermodynamics is asking to work out the changed length which got affected due to heat.

Comment: why was information about time given then?

Comment: due to length contraction/expansion, value of time period will be affected. Since Time Period is directly proportional to √L

Comment: what is loss of time ?

Comment: that's a new Q... In my humble opinion u should first get clarified with your question.

Comment: Yeah please help me get clarified with my question, If only I can understand loss of time I can try the question myself

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134811/time-period... Come in the chat room

Comment: LInk to Wikipedia article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Lets look at the equation. take the sum of the torques about point A.

$$I_A\ddot\theta+g\,L\,(M+\frac m2)\sin(\theta)=\tag 10$$

with

$$I_A=I_{\text{CM}}+m\left(\frac L2\right)^2+M\,L^2=
\frac {m\,L^2}{12}+m\left(\frac L2\right)^2+M\,L^2=L^2\,(\frac {7m}{12}+M)$$

for a small angle $~\theta~$ you obtain that

$$\omega^2=\frac gL\,\left(\frac{\frac m2+M}{\frac{7m}{12}+M}\right)=
\frac gL\,\left(\frac{\frac{m}{2\,M}+1}{\frac{7m}{12\,M}+1}\right)$$

now for  $ M >> m$

$$\omega\approx\sqrt{\frac gL}\\
T\approx\,2\pi\sqrt{\frac Lg}$$

so the period $~T~$ is depending only on the pendulum length $~L$ this is what you want to achieve by adding additional mass $~M~$ that greater then the pendulum mass $~m~$  at the end of the pendulum

Comment: I believe that the Icm of the rod should be 1/12 ML^2 ?

Comment: Thank you I will correct it